# How to make button looks same across all devices in css?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I am working on a website in which I want search button to look same across all **mobile and tablet devices**. I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93z15qpg/6/embedded/result) for that. The code which I have used for the search button **(for mobile/tablet view)** is:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #gv_search_button_2777 {
    padding-left: 5.5%;
    padding-top: 0.5%;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    padding-right: 5.5%;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gv-search-box gv-search-box-submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="all">
  <input type="submit" class="button gv-search-button" id="gv_search_button_2777" value="Search">
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

If I take the above [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93z15qpg/6/embedded/result) in the mobile view from the actual browser it looks good but if I see it from my phone it looks different.

Here is the screenshot for the Search button which I want to look on all mobile devices:

[image: search button]

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the CSS codes in my fiddle so that above screenshot is present on all devices.

On my iphone when checked on safari and chrome, I am seeing this(which is not right):

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why this question is voted for non-programming question. I am wondering what changes I need to make in the CSS codes so that I am able to get the attached screenshot across all devices.

Comment: On my phone it looks exactly the same. What kind of phone do you have, and can you include a screenshot of what you see on the phone?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Iphone. Can be a iphone issue ?

Comment: Probably. You might need to tag the question as `mobile-safari` and edit your problem statement accordingly.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Opened both on chrome and safari. It looks rounded. Check my problem statement.

Comment: On iOS, [all browsers are effectively mobile safari](https://www.zdnet.com/article/firefox-for-ios/). So it seems like a mobile safari / iOS webkit issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `appearance: none` to tell iOS Safari (and others) not to apply OS native styling to the element:

```
.button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

From there you can reset browser stylesheet attributes (e.g. margin, padding, font, etc) and apply your own custom styles.

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/93z15qpg/7/ It looks good now.

Comment: @john Note that cascading style sheet rules _cascade_. By placing `appearance: none` after your other styles with the same level of selector specificity you may end up overriding some of the styles you've already set. Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/93z15qpg/8/

Comment: You have used `appearance:none` thrice.

Comment: Errr, no. Those are vendor prefixes. This isn't a good medium for explaining CSS as a whole, alas. For what it's worth, I was referencing the placement of the appearance property declarations _after_ your other styles, not your use of the three properties as I suggested. Study the difference between your fiddle v7 and v8.

Comment: @coreyard yeah I got it now. Thanks for letting me know. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @careyward I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880510/constantly-move-resizable-draggable-image-on-the-video-when-the-browser-is-resiz?noredirect=1#comment92674974_52880510). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can give me some pointer how to proceed.

Comment: I hope all is well. I have exactly the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909283/website-footer-content-not-visible-in-iphone-7-plus) in which I am unable to see some footer content of the website in my iphone 7 plus. I am wondering if you can give me some pointer how to resolve it.